# How to define stack in Java

Tags: java

I know Java screw up stack implementation - by extending Vector. Vector is synchronized by default. Reading the java doc, and it says that to create a stack,

```
 Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
```

Since I am relative new to java. My question is: is this the best practice to define stack in Java?

Comment: thanks @pczeus. Not exact the duplication per say, just want to confirm my understanding of java practice.

Comment: I think ArrayDeque is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Read the javadoc of [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html):

> A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by **the [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface** and its implementations, which **should be used in preference to this class**. For example:
>
> ```
> Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
> ```

Even the javadoc of `Deque` says it:

> Deques can also be used as LIFO (Last-In-First-Out) stacks. **This interface should be used in preference to the legacy `Stack` class**.

*Is it "best practice" to follow the suggestions of the java documentation?*
Yeah.

Answer (score 0):

in general(not being language specific), if you want dynamic stack implementation, Linked List-based implementation provides a good and efficient stack implementation. If you don't want a dynamic implementation, using arrays would also be a very good implementation. In java Deque gives a great performance. OR if you want and alternative, you can also try this example which uses inbuilt Stack :

```
    static void showpush(Stack st, int a) {
      st.push(new Integer(a));
    //add appropriate print statements
   }

   static void showpop(Stack st) {
      Integer a = (Integer) st.pop();
    //add appropriate print statements
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Stack st = new Stack();
      showpush(st, 42);
      showpush(st, 66);
      showpush(st, 99);
      showpop(st);
      showpop(st);
      showpop(st);
   }
```

Comment: I know it is an example. two nitty picks: 1. Stack<T> might be better. 2. We do not need to do auto boxing again for new Integer(a). Also Stack implementation is awful bad from performance’s perspective. See my original question.